# Can I add an image in product description page in tabs section?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to do something like that [image: something like this].  Now I can Just add text in highlighted tab I guess . How is it possible to do that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it takes HTML so you can do whatever you want there.

Comment: for every product it would different. So where I can Store diffrent image and description  ? in which file ?

Comment: Just add the HTML to the product description field in the catalog.

Comment: I have reached in catalog now further which option ?

Comment: Create or edit a product and look for the description field. And just add your HTML there.

Comment: there is only option to add description ?? ? where I can Add other tabs data ?

Comment: That will require you to create a custom module.

Comment: how I can made a custom module for it ?  any guide line please ?

Comment: Can I change tab text like here written "highlights" to description ?

Comment: Yes on your custom theme catalog layout file.

Comment: can you tell file path please ?

Comment: Post a new question since this is a different topic.